# Extract pairs from list in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I need to extract pairs of surrounding elements from list in Groovy, so that the assertion passes:

```
assert pairs([1, 2, 3, 4]) == [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]

def pairs(List list) {
  //...
}
```

My current implementation is as follows:

```
def pairs(List list) {
    def result = []
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        result += [[list[i], list[i + 1]]]
    }
    result
}
```

Is there any more functional or groovy-way solution for that problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do:

```
def pairs(List list) {
    list.collate(2, 1, false)
}
```

THat means *"group them in groups of 2, sliding along the input list 1 entry each time, and drop any groups smaller than 2"*
And you'll get the expected result...  No need for dropping or merging or adding

Answer (score 3):

See [collate](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collate(int)):

```
groovy:000> [1,2].collate(2,1)[0 .. -2]
===> [[1, 2]]
groovy:000> [1,2,3].collate(2,1)[0 .. -2]
===> [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
groovy:000> [1,2,3,4].collate(2,1)[0 .. -2]
===> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
groovy:000> [1,2,3,4,5].collate(2,1)[0 .. -2]
===> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Using dropRight(1) may be a little clearer ([cfrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181392/cfrick)'s suggestion):

```
groovy:000> [1,2,3,4].collate(2,1).dropRight(1)
===> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Duh, didn't see the overload with the keepRemainder parameter. [Thanks, Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39472879/217324):

> Any remaining elements in the iterable after the subdivision will be dropped if keepRemainder is false

```
groovy:000> [1,2,3,4].collate(2, 1, false)
===> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: this doesn't pass my assertion, I expect just `[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]`

Comment: Nice! I just wonder whether there is some even simpler or readable solution

Comment: @Michal: you could try using inject, or eachWIthIndex. each is side-effecty so not really functional.

Comment: you can use `dropRight(1)` instead of the subsequence

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
def pairs(list){
    def evenPairs = input.collate(2)
    def oddPairs = input.drop(1).collate(2, false)
    (evenPairs + oddPairs​)​.sort()​
}
```

If it would be a way to merge arrays alternately (or order doesn't matter), it wouldn't need that ugly `sort`.